# How to digest changes in method outside angular and outside scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-factory

So I realized that doing changes outside the angular-bounds, like in an async AJAX callback, will not make angular call $apply on the scope. So far I have solved these issues by calling $scope.$apply() after changes have been made, but this time the function is not located in the same scope. The method lies in a factory, and is called from a controller.

I have tried sending the scope as a parameter from the controller to the factory, which does in fact work, but is not pretty as I expect to have many methods like this, and sending an additional parameter each time seems ugly.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can call `$apply` on the `$rootScope`, which is available for injection in services. I think that calling `$scope.$apply()` effectively calls `$rootScope.$apply()` anyway.

Comment: After using $apply a lot in that type of situation I know prefer to use promise ($q) the success/failure/notify of the promise will be injected in angular digest cycle. I found that it's more efficient and you never have to worry about a digext cycle allready in progress